# Cannot connect to cassandra from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I have some test data in my cassandra. I am trying to fetch this data from spark but I get an error like :

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.

java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.1.1}:9042
```

This is what I've done till now:

1. started `./bin/cassandra`
2. created test data using `cql` with `keyspace ="testkeyspace2"` and `table="emp"` and some keys and corresponding values.
3. Wrote **standalone.py**
4. Ran the following `pyspark` shell command.

   ```
   sudo ./bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar \
   --packages TargetHolding:pyspark-cassandra:0.2.4 \
   examples/src/main/python/standalone.py
   ```
5. Got the mentioned error.

---

**standalone.py:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Stand Alone Python Script")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
loading=sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
                        .options(table="emp", keyspace = "testkeyspace2")\
                        .load()\
                        .show()
```

I also tried with `--packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11` but I'm getting the same error.

---

**Debug:**

I checked

```
netstat -tulpn | grep -i listen | grep <cassandra_pid>
```

and saw that it is listening on port 9042.

---

**Full log trace:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/examples/src/main/python/standalone.py", line 8, in <module>
    .options(table="emp", keyspace = "testkeyspace2")\
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 139, in load
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
  File "~/Dropbox/Work/ITNow/spark/spark-1.6.0/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.
: java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.1.1}:9042
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:164)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:150)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:81)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraRDDPartitioner$.getTokenFactory(CassandraRDDPartitioner.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation$.apply(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.1.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.1.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:227)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:82)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1307)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:339)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:157)
    ... 22 more
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm really new to all this so I could use some advice. Thanks!

Comment: What is the configured rpc_address and broadcast_rpc_address (if set) in cassandra.yaml on your cassandra node?

Comment: rpc_address: localhost , rpc_port: 9160 and broadcast_rpc_address isn't set.

Comment: Ah, I bet what is happening is that cassandra is resolving localhost as 127.0.0.1 and listening on that specifically.   I just tested that locally and that seems to be the case at least for me.  'cqlsh 127.0.0.1' works, but 'cqlsh 127.0.1.1' doesn't.  Can you try that out as well and verify whether or not that is the case

Comment: I'm getting this when I try cqlsh 127.0.1.1 `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.1.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.1.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: and does it work when you try with 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yup, it works fine with 127.0.0.1!

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for confirming, that makes sense.  So the solution to this should be to either change rpc_address to 127.0.1.1 explicitly, or to change your SparkConf to use 127.0.0.1 for 'spark.cassandra.connection.host'.  I'll summarize that in an answer

Answer (score 3):

Based on our conversations in the question comments, the issue is that 'localhost' was used for `rpc_address` in your cassandra.yaml file.   Cassandra used the OS to resolve 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1 and listened on that interface explicitly.

To fix this you either need to update `rpc_address` to 127.0.1.1 in cassandra.yaml and restart cassandra or update your SparkConf to reference 127.0.0.1, i.e.:

```py
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Stand Alone Python Script")
                  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

Although one thing that seems odd to me is that spark.cassandra.connection.host also defaults to 'localhost', so it is weird to me that the spark cassandra connector resolved 'localhost' as '127.0.1.1' yet cassandra resolved it as '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: I tried both the methods and I'm getting the error `Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.1.1}:9042` . So I'm facing the same problem, but only now with a different address.

Comment: Are you sure you made the rpc_address change appropriately and restarted cassandra?  Does 'cqlsh 127.0.1.1' work now?   Are you by chance on OS X?  If so, you may need to add that interface manually, i.e. 'sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.1.1 up'.

Comment: Yes I am sure I changed the rpc_address and also restarted casandra. cqlsh 127.0.1.1 work fine and here is the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep -i listen | grep <cassandra_pid>` http://justpaste.it/qo7j. When I start cassandra, it says in the end `INFO  17:25:49 Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL`

Comment: And I'm on Linux Mint 17.

Comment: `Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL` is referring to the address chosen for the listen_address, that is what other nodes in the cluster will use for communicating with that host, but not what client connections use.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for that information! But any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: maybe this will help, this is the entire log trace. http://pasted.co/99753c14 (scroll down for the error)

Comment: Ah, this is the ticket right here: `Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.1.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))`.  My guess is you have a 3.0 C* cluster?   The problem is you are using an older version of the java driver (com.datastax.cassandra_cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.1.jar).  You should be using 3.0.0-rc1.  Which is what spark connector 1.5.0-RC1 should be using in theory.

Comment: It says in the log that you are using com.datastax.spark_spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.1.jar, but in your question you claimed you tried with '1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11'.  Can you try using that again?

Comment: Hi! I did try with '1.5.0-RC1-s_2.11' and this is the full log trace http://justpaste.it/qpdg. I'm getting errors but this time I'm not getting couldn't connect to the default 127.0.0.1. I'm getting `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.load.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;`. Any advice?

Comment: when I follow this method https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md I get the original error with `java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.1.1}:9042` again. I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: with regards to the Py4JJavaError.  I suspect some kind of incompatibility between PySpark and the version of spark that cassandra connector 1.5 is using.   If I were you, I would back level cassandra to 2.1 and use spark connector 1.4.X, you will probably have better luck there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101197/discussion-between-hackcode-and-andy-tolbert).

Answer (score 0):

I checked my linux hosts file in `/etc/hosts` and the the content was like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       <my hostname>
```

I changed it to:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       <my hostname>
```

and it worked fine.

As you can see in your own log file `line number 58` it mentions `Your hostname, ganguly resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.32 instead (on interface wlan0)` which I guess this apply o your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this next to your --packages dependency, it worked for me perfectly fine.
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host="127.0.0.1"